# Rails5 No route matches [GET] "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am write a page below:

```
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

and I got thi error:

```
Started GET "/shop-homepage.css" for ::1 at 2020-11-22 17:21:15 +0800
Started GET "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" for ::1 at 2020-11-22 17:21:15 +0800
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/shop-homepage.css"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"):
Started GET "/css/shop-homepage.css" for ::1 at 2020-11-22 17:21:15 +0800
```

my assets is like this

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzo12.png)

and i have edit application.scss. My asset is in rails's path.

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
 @import "../css/shop-homepage.css";
```

Why it just can't find .css

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 **I strongly recommend** using a gem, instead of trying to import bootstrap files on your own.

This is the standard approach:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

Comment: in this case, mark the question as "answered" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work